# Have an ExceptionMapper return different response types depending on where the exception comes from

Tags: java, rest, jersey, response, exceptionmapper

I have an ExceptionMapper called NotFoundExceptionMapper that I need to behave like this:

```
@Provider
public class NotFoundExceptionMapper implements
    ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {

    public Response toResponse(NotFoundException e) {
        if(e originated from ClassA)
            // create a complex ResponseTypeA and return it
        if(e originated from ClassB)
            // create a complex ResponseTypeB and return it
        return DefaultResponseType;
    }    
}
```

The reason I need something like that is because in my REST layer, every method in class ClassA  has essentially the exact same try & catch error handling, resulting in a lot of redundant code. The same goes for ClassB. The only difference between classA and ClassB is that methods in classA need to return a different Response type than the methods in classB.

The ExceptionMapper seems to be a great way to avoid redundant error handling code. The only thing left to do is decide where the exception comes from (ClassA or ClassB), perform some universal error handling and return the proper response type.

I have already working code for this, but I wonder if there's a more elegant way to do this. There are still a lot of things that I'm not familiar with in Jersey, so there's a good chance I missed something.

The code is fairly simple and uses UriInfo injection to discern where the exception comes from.

My ExceptionMapper:

```
@Provider
public class NotFoundExceptionMapper implements
    ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {

    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;

    public Response toResponse(NotFoundException e) {
        // MyResponseBuilder decides which response type to return:
        return MyResponseBuilder.buildResponse(uriInfo, e, Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
    }    
}
```

The class MyResponseBuilder does all the magic. It analyzes the UriInfo and returns the proper response type.

```
public class MyResponseBuilder {
    public static Response buildResponse(UriInfo uriInfo, Exception e, Status status) {
        List<Object> matchedRes = uriInfo.getMatchedResources();
        if(matchedRes.size() == 1) {
            Object res = matchedRes.get(0);
            if(res.getClass() == ClassA.class) {
                ResponseTypeA resp = new ResponseTypeA();
                // populate resp with infos
                return Response.status(status).entity(resp).build();
            }
            else if(res.getClass() == ClassB.class) {
                ResponseTypeB resp = new ResponseTypeB();
                // populate resp with infos
                return Response.status(status).entity(resp).build();
            }
        }
        return Response.status(status).build(); // default response 
    }
}
```

And while it works, it may end up causing some nasty problems <s>if there's more than one matched resource that operates on the same URI</s> Edit: turns out the Jersey specification does not allow for one @Path to have multiple resources, so that situation shouldn't happen if handled properly (finding the correct resource, that is). Still, I don't find this to be a satisfying solution.

A more elegant way to the problem would be to somehow associate a NotFoundExceptionMapper_ThatReturnsResponseTypeA directly to ClassA, and another NotFoundExceptionMapper_ThatReturnsResponseTypeB to ClassB. I haven't found any way to do so, though.

Is there a way?

Comment: If you are throwing the exception yourself, the exception takes a `Response` object as an argument. If you don't want to keep. You could even extend the exception and pass a class constructor argument if you wanted.

Comment: @peeskillet: I do throw them myself, but I don't want to mix REST code into model layer code, where the exception is actually thrown. Still, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Just throwing a not found exception in the model, IMO is already mixing "REST code" into the model :-). Like I also said, you can extend the exception and just construct the `Response` in the constructor, calling `super(Response...)` if you don't want "REST code" to _appear_ in the model class. That's another option.

Comment: The NotFound exception is of my own design and is thrown if a resource cannot be found in a database. There's other exception types as well, none of which derive from Jersey's WebApplicationException. The second option would nail a specific response type down to a specific exception (the extended one), that would defeat the purpose. Furthermore, the exception might be thrown by a third party library, something I have no control over.

Comment: Oh nvm. I though it was the Jersey NotFoundException